# send html rendered by react as email body in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I have a react application. It has two pages - AddStatus and ViewStatus. Both are react components.

My requirement is - I have to send an email daily at a particular time with details as seen in ViewStatus screen.

I can set up node-mailer and node-scheduler to do that. But how do i render the ViewStatus component from backend. How do i get the HTML of viewStatus screen.

I tried using renderToString method of ReactDOMServer like below in my server.js but getting error

```js
var App = React.createFactory(require('../ViewStatus'))

var p = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(App());
```

```
  Error: locals[0] does not appear to be a `module` object with Hot Module replace
ment API enabled. You should disable react-transform-hmr in production by using
  `env` section in Babel configuration. See the example in README: https://github.
 com/gaearon/react-transform-hmr
```

Another approach I though of is using react-router but I am not sure how to trigger the route from backend.

How do I get the HTML of my viewstatus component in my server.js

Answer (score 0):

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOMServer = require("react-dom/server");

var MyComponent = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
      return React.DOM.div({}, "Text");
    }
});

var App = React.createFactory(MyComponent)

var html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(App());

console.log("HTML =\n", html);
```

Output:

```
HTML =
 <div data-reactroot="" data-reactid="1" data-react-checksum="-1164111617">Text</div>
```

Works for me, as your error says, seems like you have issues with the React Hot Loader .. Your code seems to be fine.

Comment: Yes this simple code works for me too.If I just do this in my server.js. But when I am importing my component in server.js I am getting error

Comment: I am able to get it worked after i removed react-hmre but when i load my components it starts failing on the dependencies.First Jquery then i included jquery in my server.js (which is not right way) but then it starts failing for document not defined.What is teh right way to use renderToString ?